# Python threads and strings

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, buffering

I am new to threads and multiprocessing.  I have some code in which I start a process and I wanted the output to show an active waiting state of something like this

```
wating....
```

The code is similiar to this below:

import threading
    import time

```
class ThreadExample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pause = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.second_thread).start()
        #  Some other processes
        print("Waiting", end="")
        while self.pause:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(".", end="")
        print("Hooray!")

    def second_thread(self):
        print("timer started")
        time.sleep(3)
        self.pause = False
        print("timer finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadExample()
```

When I run the code above, I receive the output:

```
timer started
Do something else..timer finished
.
Hooray!
```

not a big surprise, except that only the 'timer started' appears at the beginning and the rest of the text appears in an instant at the end.

If I change the line print(".", end="") to print("."), I receive the following output:

```
timer started
Do something else.
.
timer finished
.
Hooray
```

where the dots appear in 1 second increments, which was my intention.

Is there a way to get the 'Waiting...' on one line without the end=""?

And secondly I am guessing this is something to do with the internals of the print() function, and if not, should I perform the threading in another manner?  I do not think the problem is the GIL as I have tried multiprocess.Process and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to `print` buffering. It is flushed on `\n` and on some other occasions (like buffer overflow or program exit). Instead of `print` try this:

```
import sys

def unbuffered_print(msg):
    sys.stdout.write(msg)
    sys.stdout.flush()

...
unbuffered_print('.')
```

everywhere.

Comment: Note: On modern Python (3.3 and higher), [`print` can be passed `flush=True` to make it flush after printing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), while preserving the full power/flexibility of the `print` function. So `print(end='.', flush=True)` or `print('.', end='', flush=True)` would also do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite useful.